# protoc producing invalid java code

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I've been using protobuf to generate intra-backend messages but when I moved to a new laptop and set up protoc again it seems it doesn't generate working java code anymore.

I'm on the latest Ubuntu 16.04 and have downloaded the latest protoc

```
$ protoc --version
libprotoc 3.5.1
```

Building it, without errors or warnings, with

```
protoc --java_out=<javapath> --python_out=<pythonpath> messages.proto
```

The messages shown by Eclipse / maven are these:

```
The method parseUnknownFieldProto3(CodedInputStream, UnknownFieldSet.Builder, ExtensionRegistryLite, int) is undefined for the type MessageA.Request    Messages.java   ...path, line etc...

snip, more of the same for other messages

Messages.Shutdown   Messages.java   ...path...
The method setUnknownFieldsProto3(UnknownFieldSet) is undefined for the type GeneratedMessageV3.Builder<Messages.Request.Builder>   Messages.java   ...path, line etc...

snip, more of the same
```

If I manually rename `parseUnknownFieldProtoc3` to `parseUnknownField` and same for SetUnknownFields the error goes away but that feels like the wrong solution.

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you using matching protoc compiler and library code versions? meaning: the library references / imports: are they also 3.5.1?

Comment: I just realized the .jar we have in the classpath is 3.3.0, I feel rather silly currently. Trying to locate a prebuilt 3.5.1 jar to test with.

Comment: the other option would be to use the `protoc` from v3.3.0: https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases/tag/v3.3.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you're using mismatched generated code and library code. If you're using `protoc` 3.5.1 you need the library code from 3.5.1; alternatively, if you're using library 3.3.0 - you need the `protoc` from 3.3.0.

All the releases are [here](https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases), with [3.5.1](https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases/tag/v3.5.1) and [3.3.0](https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases/tag/v3.3.0)

Comment: I didn't find a prebuilt jar on github but I did find it here http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.protobuf/protobuf-java/3.5.1